# Pass a Parameter to a Controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I would like to pass the `id` of an `object` to a `controller` in `laravel`. Basically I've a page that displays the information relating to a `book`. The user has the option to add `themes` to that book. The line below is the link they click in order to open the create theme `form`:

```
<a href="{{action('ThemeController@create')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Add Theme</a>
```

and the `ThemeController` method:

```
public function create(){
        $books = Book::all();
        return View::make('theme.create', compact('books'));
    }
```

Currently this brings up a Form with a list of all of my books in a dropdown. I would rather just pass the `id` of the book the user was on prior to being brought to this form and use that instead. Is there any way I can do that? I've also included my `routes.php` file:

```
Route::model('book', 'Book');
//Show pages
Route::get('/books', 'BookController@index');
Route::get('book/create', 'BookController@create');
Route::get('book/edit/{book}', 'BookController@edit');
Route::get('book/delete/{book}', 'BookController@delete');
Route::get('book/view/{book}', 'BookController@view');
////Handle form submissions
Route::post('book/create', 'BookController@handleCreate');
Route::post('book/edit', 'BookController@handleEdit');
Route::post('book/delete', 'BookController@handleDelete');


//Themes
Route::model('theme', 'Theme');
Route::get('/themes', 'ThemeController@index');
Route::get('theme/create', 'ThemeController@create');
Route::get('theme/edit/{book}', 'ThemeController@edit');
Route::get('theme/delete/{book}', 'ThemeController@delete');
Route::get('theme/view/{book}', 'ThemeController@view');
Route::post('theme/create', 'ThemeController@handleCreate');
Route::post('theme/edit', 'ThemeController@handleEdit');
Route::post('theme/delete', 'ThemeController@handleDelete');
```

Comment: I'm assuming you did not use Laravel's Artisan Controller Make function?

Comment: I didn't use it for the `Conrollers` but had been using it for the `Migrations`

Comment: Aah okay, well, I would recommend using Resource Controllers.. You're pretty much using that structure already. However, Resource Controllers will simplify your Route structure, by quite a lot :).

Comment: Unless of course you're not building a RESTful application and would prefer not to use Put and Delete at all. Then I understand.

Answer (score 4):

You can still use normal $_GET methodology.
On your route:
`book/create`
You could simply request.
`book/create?book_id=xxyy`
Then in your controller create function

```
public function create(){
    $bookId = Input::get('book_id');
    $books = Book::all()->where('book_id' => $bookId);
    return View::make('theme.create', compact('books'));
}
```

**PLEASE NOTE:**
I haven't used Laravel in a while, don't trust that elequont query :P.. I was just putting a theoretical "where" in there.

And here http://laravel.com/docs/requests#basic-input, you will note this:

> "You do not need to worry about the HTTP verb used for the request, as
>   input is accessed in the same way for all verbs."

So whether you're using get, put, post or delete, whatever you wrapped in your header, you will be able to find using `Input` Class.

**EDIT**
Just needed to add, that you won't need to modify your routes at all. This is just a Simple GET parameter in a GET request. Just like in any other application.